# Why scala's TreeSet returns SortedSet

Tags: scala, treeset

Is there a reason that the object `TreeSet.apply` method returns `SortedSet` and not `TreeSet`?

The following code won't compile in scala 2.7

```
val t:TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal answer is because `apply()` is [implemented](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_7_final/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSet.scala?view=markup)  in terms of `++`, which is defined in `SortedSet`, and hence returns a `SortedSet`. `++` then goes on to use `+`, which **is** defined in `TreeSet`, so you can cast it back to `TreeSet` if it's critical (though I wouldn't recommend it, as it is implementation dependent and may change over time!).

What do you need from TreeSet that you can't get from SortedSet?

I'm not sure what the rationale behind the design decision is, though it looks like it has changed in 2.8.

Comment: I I wouldn't want a `TreeSet`, I wouldn't ask for a `TreeSet` would I?  Should `List(1,2,3)` give back `Iterable`? My main problem with `SortedSet` is that I can't remove an elment from it and keep its type a `SortedSet`. What you actually said here is "yes sir, it's a bag" ;-).

Comment: Yep, that's certainly a valid use case, and I didn't notice that a lot of those methods aren't overridden on `SortedSet`. It might be worth asking about the API design on the mailing list. In the meantime, you can either down-cast the result or build the set up using `TreeSet.empty` and `+` (as you're probably already aware).

Answer (score 5):

This has been identified as a short coming of the current scala collection library, and is addressed in the revamped collection library that is part of scala 2.8. See http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/3# for the gory details.